# Sandboxing javascript module

Tags: javascript, sandbox

Is it possible to sandbox javascript module from DOM manipulation? Fo example

```
var Core = { 
    register: function(config){config.init()},
    publicApi: {
        msgbox: function(msg){alert(msg)} 
    } 
}
Core.register({
    name: 'testmodule',
    init: function(){
        /* from there i want to see only function defined in Core.publicApi, no jQuery direct access, no DOM */
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, somewhat: you can sandbox the function, but its callees will also be sandboxed. That means even stuff in `Core.publicApi` won't be able to access `document` and the like. Or, at least, there's no bulletproof sandboxing in Javascript that will allow that bridging.

You can cripple what's available by temporarily overwriting the `window` variable:

```
var window = {"Core": Core};
```

But then **no** global variable (even such as `alert`) will exist for the callees. This will most likely break your API.

You can add another member (like `_unsandboxed` or whatever) into the new `window` variable to allow your API to access the members. But, as I said, it's not bulletproof since sandboxed functions can still access `_unsandboxed`.